# Phpmyadmin updating rows with random string

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

So I lately added a feature for users to have their own PIN which where they can login with.
But the feature was not created when the users first joined, thus I'm trying to insert random numbers into the PIN row that are ofcourse unique. Because the feature was not added before most of the rows got created, I'm now stuck with an pre-set value in most of the tables.

I wondered if anyone knew a script/command in PhpMyAdmin to update every row with a random number ranging from 4 to 5 digits.

Table:

```
Unique_ID
ID
Username
Gold
Bank
Troop
Head
Body
Gloves
Legs
Feet
**PIN**
```

PIN needs to be automaticly set, the user can't set it himself. The system would be useless otherwise.
And the data is not hashed, since theres already an protective script with Python.

Comment: and shouldn't you be hashing it?

Comment: I don't know about phpmyadmin but this should be relatively simple and straightforward to do with either php or Python by making a quick connection to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this:

```
update table set pin = FLOOR(1111 + (RAND() * 88889));
```

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand for an explaniation.

Comment: nope.. did you replace `table` with your table name and `pin` with your real field name? this works as it should `SELECT FLOOR( 1111 + ( RAND( ) *88889 ))`